# WorkManager: Call doWork() immediately for test purposes

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

If I have a `PeriodicWorkRequest` I can set a time intervall - which minimum is 15 minutes.
But how can I test if my `doWork()` method is working without waiting for 15 minutes?

Is it maybe possible to use `OneTimeWorkRequest` for test purposes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing stopping you from using `OneTimeWorkRequest`.

```
val work = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java).build()
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(work)
```

Bear in mind, that this will not allow you to test that your `Worker` will fire after a set number of minutes, like when using `PeriodicWorkRequest`. It will however let you test that your code works, without needing to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the minimum time interval for `PeriodicWorkRequest` is 15 minutes and it can't be changed since it is hardcoded in `PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS`.

However, for test purpose you can call doWork() method of your `PeriodicWorkRequest` whenever you want with the help of [WorkManagerTestInitHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/WorkManagerTestInitHelper) available in [androidx.work.testing](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/package-summary).

Add the following dependency in the build.gradle file for your app or module:

```
//Current stable release is 2.3.4
androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:2.3.4"
```

Next, you need to use `setPeriodDelayMet` method available with [TestDriver](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/testing/TestDriver) which can be used to indicate that an interval is complete and executes PeriodicWorkRequest sooner than MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS (15 minutes).
Sample code:

```
@Test
public void testPeriodicWork(Context context) throws Exception {
    // Setup input data
    Data input = new Data.Builder().put(KEY_1, 1).put(KEY_2, 2).build();

    // Create periodic work request
    PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 15,  TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                       .setInputData(input)
                                       .build();
    // Enqueue periodic request
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(WORKER_TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, request);

    // Initialize testDriver
    TestDriver testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver();

    // Tells the testing framework the period delay is met, this will execute your code in doWork() in MyWorker class
    testDriver.setPeriodDelayMet(request.getId());

}
```

Read more about testing [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest) at [Testing Periodic Work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/integration-testing#periodic-work)